# Single Source Multi commodity transportation problem in PuLP

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, pulp

I am currently working on a project, that I am trying to solve using a transportation problem. Essentially what I need to do is assign students to their schools based on where they live. Since they can study different things I am modeling it as a Multi commodity transportation problem. One of the restrictions that have been imposed on the project is that every student of the same study direction and the same place of living need to be assigned to the same school.
This would give the following mathematical model:
[image: Model]

I have managed to implement all constraints except for that last one. My attempt was to do it the following way.

```
for g in communes:
    for l in studies:
        model.addConstraint(pulp.LpConstraint(
            e=pulp.lpSum(x[g,s,l] - students[g,l] if x[g,s,l]==students[g,l] else x[g,s,l] for s in schools if (g,s,l) in x),
            sense=pulp.LpConstraintEQ,
            name='Unique_assignment[{}, {}]'.format(g,l),
            rhs=0
        ))
```

Adding this last constraint causes PuLP to ignore all other ones, which I do not understand. Can anyone give me a pointer as to how I would need to go about implementing a condition like this?

Comment: I don't understand the combination of the first and last constraints. `d_gl` is obviously a natural number, but if `x_gsl \in {0, d_gl}`, doesn't that mean that only one of all `x_gsl` can be 1 and all others must be 0 for every `s \in S`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are trying to implement an "all or nothing" constraint on `x` and only want it to be zero or the demand.  That's not going to work too well and the constraint you are trying to code with the conditional constraint isn't legal as that would imply that you want the solver to use one set of equations under certain variable values and another set of equations in a different case.

On the bright side, the fix is pretty easy.  You can just cast `x` as a binary variable and wherever you need to get to quantity, multiply it by demand.  So in your objective and capacity constraints you would need to multiply by the parameter `d`.  And you will need to modify your demand constraint such that the sum across all schools for `x` is 1.

Give it a whirl and comment back if stuck.